# How to link a list table view to another table view for details using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, model, invoice

I am viewing a list on the 1st page and on the 2nd page it should link using the same id from the database on the 1st page, but the 2nd page its details page.

1st page - listview

2nd page - details

Here is what I have already tried

Example: http://abctutorial.com/Post/53/mvc5-master-detail-edit-using-aspnet--jquery--razor

## The Model called: "Ordering" and its display on the ListView

```
        public Ordering()
        {
            this.Invoice_Line_Item = new HashSet<Invoice_Line_Items>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int order_id { get; set; }
        public Guid? CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int? CustId { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        [StringLength(34)]
        public string invoice_number { get; set; }
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ClientFirstname { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ClientLastname { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string trackingorderno { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string DeliveryNote { get; set; }
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Agent { get; set; }
        public DateTime? date_order_placed { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Invoice_Line_Items> Invoice_Line_Item { 
        get; set; }
```

## ListView page for "Ordering"

```
@model IEnumerable<LifestyleAdminOriginal.Models.Ordering>

          @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
             <tr>
              <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.invoice_number)
              </td>
               <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientFirstname) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientLastname)
               </td>
               <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailId)
               </td>
               <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MobileNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                <span class="label label-danger">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</span>
                </td>
                <td>
               @Html.ActionLink("View", "NewOrdersDetails", new { id = item.CustId })
                 </td>
                 </tr>
                }
```

## Details page for "Invoice_Line_Items"

```
<div class="row">
                                    @if (Model.Count() != 0)
                                    {
                                        foreach (var item in Model)
                                        {
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                <div class="invoice-sp">
                                                    <table class="table table-hover">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr>

                                                                <th>Service</th>
                                                                <th>Item</th>
                                                                <th>Gender</th>
                                                                <th>Unit Price</th>
                                                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                                                <th>Total</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                @foreach (var inv in item.Invoice_Line_Item)
                                                            {
                                                                        <th>@inv.service</th>
                                                                        <td>@inv.item</td>
                                                                    <td>@inv.gender</td>
                                                                    <td>@inv.price</td>
                                                                    <td>@inv.quantity</td>
                                                                    <td>@inv.price</td>
                                                            }
                                                            </tr>

                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                             }
                                        }
                                        </div>
```

## Listview Controller for "Ordering"

```
public ActionResult NewOrders()
        {
            var count = db.Orderings.Where(s => s.trackingorderno == "New Order").Count();
            ViewBag.totalall = count;

            return View(db.Orderings.ToList().Where(x => x.trackingorderno == "New Order").Select(x => x));
        }
```

## Detailsview Controller for "Invoice_Line_Items" and "Ordering"

```
public ActionResult NewOrdersDetails(int? CustId)
        {
            if (CustId == null)
            {
                return new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            List<Ordering> OrderAndCustomerList = db.Orderings.ToList();
            
            if (OrderAndCustomerList == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(OrderAndCustomerList);
        }
```

Basically, whenever a user clicks "View" on listview page, it should take them to the details page where it shows the invoice line items and displays the customer details as well on one page which is "DetailsView"

Comment: what is the name of the controller the `NewOrdersDetails` method belongs to, `DetailsViewController`? also, what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the detailed info using CustId?

Comment: yes correct @benmartin101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the answer from the following example on the below link. I used the **ICollection** on the model **Ordering**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

```
    **Ordering Model**
    [ForeignKey("order_id")]
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice_Line_Items> Invoice_Line_Item { get; set; }

    **Invoice_Line_Items Model**
    public virtual Ordering Ordering { get; set; }



         **Details Page**
         <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Service</th>
                <th>Department</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Invoice_Line_Item)
            {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.invoice_number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.service)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.department)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vat)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.grandtotal)
            </td>
        </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In First table Where You Show Main Data and Second Table Detail Of the First table data 
so you have to take detail table content id in Main Table content and send it to second page with detail id from main table.

Comment: I am trying this link [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application) but it gives me an error that says: invalid column name "Ordering_order_id" @Vijay Dwivedi

Comment: Welcome to SO! So exactly how you propose to do that? That is a comment rather than a  answer. Until you don´t have enough Rep. you should give a better answer or delete.